# Запуск Ansible из-под рута на Cygwin

Tags: ssh, ansible, cygwin

Задача: запускать баш-скрипты на конечных серверах из-под рута. Машина с ансиблом - винда+сигвин.
И тут возникает проблема: не могу подключиться к машинам под рутом.

Я и под обычным пользователем не мог этого делать, но смог решить эту проблему через: "ssh-keygen -t rsa" -> "ssh-copy-id my_user@server1" || "ssh-copy-id my_user@server2".
То есть сгенерил ключик и раздал его серверам. В общем, решил эту проблему. И теперь то, что не требует рута, у меня запускается нормально.

А вот все то, что требует рута - не запускается никак.
Сразу ворох проблем:

1. На сигвине нет "рута", поэтому непонятно под кем генерировать ключ.
2. допустим сгенерировал (ну, решили первый пункт) - как его передать на сервера? И куда положить?
3. Как указать ансиблу, что запускать нужно под рутом?
4. Вычитал, что рут запускается так "remote_user: root". Но он пишет ошибку: "`Failed to connect to the host via ssh: my_user@server1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).`"
   Прошу обратить внимание, какого пользователя он пишет: не "root", все также мой пользователь (my_user).

В общем, суть проблемы описал.
Задача: запустить скрипт под рутом (потому что иначе он не отработает). Как решить эту задачу?
Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, сам разобрался, что нужно делать. Только не разобрался, почему это работает.

Шаг первый: записать в плейбук `become: true`:

```
---
- hosts:
    test_hosts
  #remote_user:
    #root
  become: true
  #sudo: yes
  vars:
    source_path: "/tmp/source_fluentd"
```

Как видно, ремоут_юзер не сработал, а "судо: ес" скоро удалят, как устаревшее.

Шаг второй: запускаем ансибл с параметром -K: `ansible-playbook ./your_playbook.yml -K`

Все это приводит к тому, что мой скрипт удаленно запустился и заработал. И выполнил то, что можно выполнить только под судо-юзером.
Значит, способ работает.

А вот то, что я не понял: под каким пользователем я запустился. Как указать, пользователя, под которым я хочу запускаться?
Просто все это я делал на тестовом сервере, где я имею рут-права. А на боевом, что логично, прав нет. И нужно, когда буду отдавать плейбук, запустить под боевым пользователем. Только как?

Comment: А вот то, что я не понял: под каким пользователем я запустился. Как указать, пользователя, под которым я хочу запускаться? Просто все это я делал на тестовом сервере, где я имею рут-права. А на боевом, что логично, прав нет. И нужно, когда буду отдавать плейбук, запустить под боевым пользователем. Только как?

Comment: `become` - это абстракция для `sudo` и `runas`. Говоря `become: yes` ты говоришь `sudo blablabla`. А `sudo` по умолчанию запрашивает права рута. Так что можно ещё `become_user:` использовать.

Comment: @don-rumata так в этом все и дело: я понимаю, что делает бекон - только непонятно, для какого юзера он это делает. Как мне заSSHшиться под определенным юзером. Как `become_user` авторизуется?

Comment: `group_vars/*.yml` - там указан `ansible_user`, `ansible_password`, возможно `ansible_connection`. А можно ли повышать права - прописано в `/etc/sudoers` конкретной тачки.

Comment: нужен безпаральный вход. Пароль - это ненадежно. Поэтому я не могу ничего указывать. Могу только генерировать ключи.

Comment: в целом, свою проблему непонимания ssh-авторизации я описал тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922261/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-ssh-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f

Comment: Пароль - как пример и как один из способов. Он будет всё ещё ненадёжен, если у тебя физически и географически изолированная сеть?

Comment: `ansible_user` ты всё равно как-то должен передать.

Comment: я понял. Спасибо. Просто я не сторонник конфигов - не  люблю, когда с статику запихивают то, что в теории, может довольно легко измениться. Типа польозвателя, из-под которого нужно запуститься.

Comment: Как запихнуть инфу в переменную - это уже твоё дело.