# Как работает SSH-авторизация?

Tags: ssh, авторизация, ssh-key

Не могу понять никак, как работает SSH-авторизация. Везде написано, как она устроена, ее механизм.
Но везде упускается то, что для меня самое главное - "а почему"? А почему она работает, как она распознает юзера, как нужного юзера?

Вот есть Сервер "сервак", и на нем есть два пользователя "админ" (с рут-правами) и "юзер" (который бесправный холоп).
И есть два человека: Вася и Игорь. Игорь - админ "сервака", а Вася - простой пользователь.

Они оба хотят войти со своих домашних компов на сервер. В начале известно только адрес сервера. Ничего другого нет.

Что должна сделать каждая из сторон - Игорь, Вася и "сервак" - чтобы люди авторизовались со своими правами на сервер? То есть кто, что и когда должен генерировать?

То есть мне как раз непонятен этот момент: как удаленный пользователь опознается, как верифицированный пользователь, обладающий нужным набором прав?
И что нужно сделать, чтобы зайти под другим пользователем (Васе стать админом)?

Comment: Имя пользователя да пароль. За набор прав SSH в целом не отвечает

Comment: @andreymal мне нужно безпарольную авторизацию.

Comment: сейчас я делаю так: генерирую ключ ssh-keygen. Потом утилитой ssh-copy-id (ей?) раздаю ключи серверам. После чего подключаюсь к ним без пароля. При этом я не понимаю, как SSH определяет, под каким пользователем меня нужно впустить на сервер.

Comment: Всё, чем занимается ssh-copy-id — это помещает публичную часть ключа в файл `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` на сервере, соответственно пользователь для этого ключа серверу известен. А при следующем подключении ключ проверяется [сложным матаном асимметричной криптографии](https://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/28/28/lecture/20422) (и это не специфично для SSH, в основе того же HTTPS те же алгоритмы, и некоторые веб-сайты позволяют аутентификацию по ключу)

Comment: вот как раз часть, которая по ссылке мне известна - не раз читал об этом алгоритме. А часть "соответственно пользователь для этого ключа серверу известен" мне не понятна. Как и когда пользователь стал известен? Вот как мне "чистого" пользователя (например, мой домашний компьютер) сделать известным серверу? Вот именно на это я и ищу ответ.

Comment: «Как и когда пользователь стал известен?» — он передаётся во время подключения всегда, независимо от паролей или ключей. Кроме того, один ключ может позволять входить нескольким разным пользователям (если всем ssh-copy-id сделать, конечно) — просто указывайте нужное имя пользователя при подключении (по умолчанию берётся ваше текущее имя пользователя на локальном компьютере)

Comment: В этом и проблема многих инструментов: самое простое и важное - не объясняют. А сложные, но ненужные части везде описаны. И даже в универе их преподают. Но вот мне совершенно неинтересно, как внутри устроен ССШ. Мне важнее, как заставить сервер меня узнавать.

Comment: Ваше имя пользователя передаётся во время подключения, вот и всё

Comment: @andreymal то есть никакой магии нет? Просто сравнение двух строк? И если где-то на "вражеском" сервере есть пользователь с такой же строкой "логин" и он сопрет ключ - он войдет? Но если ему не повезло - и у него другое имя, он не войдет?

Comment: «и он сопрет ключ» — не понял о чём речь

Comment: значит, что у него каким-то образом появится секретный ключ, который должен храниться только на компьютере пользователя.

Comment: но речь не об этом. А о том, что сравнение идет просто но буквам: логин сервера и логин клиента?

Comment: «каким-то образом появится секретный ключ» Ну если кому-то удастся украсть секретный ключ с вашего компьютера — то да, войдёт. (Поэтому нужно дополнительно защищать ключ — сюрприз! — паролем)

Comment: «сравнение идет просто но буквам» — я не копался детально во внутренностях ssh, но не знаю причин, почему должно быть не просто по буквам

Comment: @andreymal, "почему должно быть не просто по буквам". Потому что буквам нельзя доверять. Они легко совпадают и не несут идентификационной ценности. А вот сложный ключ вряд ли совпадет. Ключ, по моему представлению, и должен был определять пользователя.

Comment: Вы хотите странного. Если «сложный ключ вряд ли совпадёт», то зачем того же самого требовать от имени пользователя, если уже есть ключ? Определяют пользователя имя пользователя **и** ключ, без ключа (или пароля) имя пользователя полностью бесполезно.

Comment: я имею ввиду то, что на домашнем компе у меня пользователь Elliott. А на рабочем - hdp_agent. И значит, что я не войду с домашнего компьютера. Так как на рабочей станции нет такого пользователя. Ну, или мне придется создать на домашнем компьютере hdp_agent.

Comment: `ssh hdp_agent@адрессервера` да и всё, а дальше сервер будет проверять ключ по содержимому файла `/home/hdp_agent/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Answer (score 2):

это практически дубликат другого вопроса: [Как поэтапно происходит SSH-аутентификация?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629598/178576)

---

остальная часть вопроса, не раскрытая по ссылке выше:

> как удаленный пользователь опознается, как верифицированный пользователь, обладающий нужным набором прав?
> В начале известно только адрес сервера. Ничего другого нет.

неправильно! **обязательно** передаётся имя учётной записи на сервере. то самое, что указывается либо непосредственно в [*url*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) (`имя@сервер`), либо опцией `-l имя`, а если не указано ни там ни там, то будет передано имя локального пользователя.

> И что нужно сделать, чтобы зайти под другим пользователем (Васе стать админом)?

очевидно: указать **нужное** имя пользователя сервера (любым из двух перечисленных выше способов)

> Что должна сделать каждая из сторон - Игорь, Вася и "сервак" - чтобы люди авторизовались со своими правами на сервер?

если Игорю надо авторизоваться на сервере под именем `имярек`, то, во-первых, пользователь с таким именем должен существовать на сервере, во-вторых, в файле `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` этого пользователя должна быть вписана отдельной строкой публичная часть ключа, секретной частью которой обладает этот самый Игорь.

---

p.s. для краткости изложения описаны только общие концепции, без множества оговорок и уточнений.

---

ответы на связанные вопросы в комментариях:

> в какой момент можно передавать имя_пользователя?

имя пользователя, под которым следует авторизоваться, указывается в аргументах программе *ssh*. программа *ssh* передаёт его программе *sshd* (работающей на удалённом компьютере) во втором поле [запроса на аутентификацию](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4252#section-5).

> что содержит файл ключа - разве он содержит имя, а не просто сам ключ?

файл с публичной частью ключа содержит публичную часть ключа, а файл с секретной частью ключа содержит секретную часть ключа (технически в этой части ключа содержится *в том числе и* публичная часть). да, в файле, содержащем публичную часть ключа может присутствовать опциональный комментарий, в который программа, создающая этот файл, заносят имя пользователя, запустившего эту программу. данный комментарий предназначен для человека, и игнорируется программами *ssh/sshd*.

Comment: спасибо. Но как раз по ссылке указано все то, что я итак знаю. Я не знал, как передается имя пользователя. Кстати, я так и не понял, в какой момент можно передавать имя_пользователя? И что содержит файл ключа - разве он содержит имя, а не просто сам ключ?

Comment: дополнил ответ.